# How to build complex relationships in CoreData correctly?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am dealing with CoreData, for training, I decided to create a small application for recording user income and expenses. CoreData tutorials all contain To-Do-List examples, and I haven't found any good examples that would help me.

```
// MARK: - Grammar 
// I want to apologize for grammatical errors in the text. Unfortunately,
// English is not my native language, so in some places I used a translator.
```

If something is not clear, I will definitely try to explain it again.

When I began to think over how I would implement the application, I assumed that the most convenient way would be to save all user operations and make calculations in the application in the right places. So far, abstract, since It seems to me that this has little to do with the question, if you need to be more precise, I can provide a complete idea.

So, I'm going to save the user model, which will have the following data:

User operations (Operation type) - all operations will be saved, each operation includes the category for which the operation was performed, as well as the amount in currency.

User-selected categories (Category Type) - Categories that will be used for expenses or income when adding an operation.

Wallets (Type Wallet) - User's wallets, Everything is simple, the name, and the balance on it.

Budget Units (BudgetUnit Type) - These are user budgets, contains a category, and a budget for it. For example:  Products - 10.000 $

[image: Models picture]

When I started building dependencies in CoreData, I got a little strange behavior.

[image: strange behavior]

That is, the user has a relationship on the same category model as the Budget Unit and Operation. Something tells me that it won't work that way.
I want the user categories to be independent, he selected them, and I'm going to display them on the main screen, and each operation will have its own category model

[image: I want]

In the picture above, the category model is used 3 times, the same model.

This is roughly how I represent the data structure that I would like to see. Different models have their own category model, independently of the others.

I think it could be implemented using 3 different models with the same values, but it seems to me that this approach is considered wrong.

So how do you properly implement the data model so that everything works as expected? I would be grateful for any help!

**--- EDIT ---**

As a solution to the problem, I can create multiple entities as `Category` (Example bellow)

[image: example]

But I don't know if this is good practice

Comment: This looks a bit overly complicated to me. As I see it a User has one (or many) wallets, a Wallet contains many operations (I would name them transactions) where the balance of wallet is equal of the sum of the money attribute on the operations. Each Operation has a Category (and Category is used nowhere else).  I left out BudgetUnit because I am not sure what it is for. So all in al a User has only a relationship to Operation (and maybe BudgetUnit) but no more.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
The point is that categories are also used.

The user has selected categories, when the user will add a new expense or income, he will need to select one of the categories to save the transaction

Comment: Totally agree with @JoakimDanielson - Just add that in cases where you need to share an entity like 'Category' among other entities, you can simply replace the direct relationship by an UUID. This avoids many troubles. Then you have a getter in your manager such `fetchCategory(with uuid: UUID)` to retrieve the shared object. This approach removes many knots in the model and greatly simplify the scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into several other open source projects and saw a solution to the problem.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

There is no need to save the categories for the user, you can simply save the categories in the application by adding the `IsSelected` and `ID` parameter to them in order to change these parameters when you select a category, and immediately understand which ones you need to display.

For budgets and operations (transactions) , we only need to save the category `ID` to immediately display the correct one.

For example:

[image: Example]

Thanks **@JoakimDanielson** and **@Moose for helping**. It gave me a different view of the subject.